# segmentation fault by using virtual method in C++

Tags: c++, oop, object

I got a C++ object oriented program that was working right. I have decided to modify it by adding some polimorpysm definining a class hierarchy with virtual methods. When I call the virtual method it produces an fault segmentation error, likely because I have trash in the object.

This is the call and the warming up

```
  GPUAntColony *colony; // Base class
  GPUAntColonyConfiguration config;
  set_config(config);
  set_initial_pheromone(problem, config);
  colony = (GPUAntColony *)new GPUSimpleAntColony(problem, config);//inhereted class
  colony->run(); //Virtual method
```

Now let me show you the base class

```
 class GPUAntColony {

 private:

    void reset_ants() {
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<configuration_.number_of_ants;i++) {
         ants_[i]= Util::random_number(problem_->number_of_vertices());
    }
  }

  void initialize_Pheromone(){
   for(unsigned int i=0; i<problem_->number_of_vertices()*problem_->number_of_vertices();i++) {
       pheromones_[i]=(float)configuration_.initial_pheromone;
   }
  }


   protected:
  float * pheromones_;
    float alpha_;
    float beta_;
  unsigned int iterations;
    GPUAntColonyConfiguration::LocalSearchType local_search_type_;
  GPUAntColonyConfiguration configuration_;
  unsigned int * ants_;
    GPUOptimizationProblem *problem_;

  public:  


 ///Class Constructor for the Class GPU Ant Colony        
 GPUAntColony(GPUOptimizationProblem *problem, const GPUAntColonyConfiguration &config){

   iterations=4096; 
      problem_ = problem; // Including distance array
   configuration_ = config;
   ants_= (unsigned int*) malloc(config.number_of_ants*sizeof(unsigned int));   
      pheromones_ = (float *) malloc(problem->number_of_vertices()*problem->number_of_vertices()*sizeof(float)); 
   alpha_ = config.alpha;
   std::cout << "alpha_ " << alpha_ << std::endl;
      beta_ = config.beta;
      local_search_type_ = config.local_search;
 }

  virtual void run();  

  virtual ~GPUAntColony() {
      delete problem_;
      free(ants_);
      free (pheromones_);
    };


};
```

The definition of the child class

```
class GPUSimpleAntColony : public GPUAntColony{
public:
    GPUSimpleAntColony(GPUOptimizationProblem *problem, const GPUAntColonyConfiguration &config);
    void run();
};
```

And finally the implementation of such method

```
void GPUAntColony::run(){ 
  reset_ants();
  initialize_Pheromone();  
}


GPUSimpleAntColony::GPUSimpleAntColony(GPUOptimizationProblem *problem, const GPUAntColonyConfiguration &config):GPUAntColony(problem, config) {
}



void GPUSimpleAntColony::run() {
 GPUAntColony::run();
  antColonyGPULauncher(configuration_.number_of_ants, problem_->number_of_vertices(), problem_->get_distances(), pheromones_,ants_,alpha_, beta_,
             configuration_.evaporation_rate, iterations, 0, 0, 0, 0, ACO_SIMPLE);
}
```

Hopefully you can help me.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the stack trace of the dump when you get the seg fault?  This may have nothing to do with the virtual and everything to do with 'antColonyGPULauncher'

Comment: Yes that's what i though at the beggining but nothing is wrong with the antColonyGPUlauncher, because does not reach this line of code. The segmentation fault is when calls the virtual method run().

Comment: @Jose: Can you add the stack-trace from e.g. GDB to your question anyway?

Comment: @Jose: If you change the first line to `GPUSimpleAntColony *colony;`, does the problem go away?

Comment: Number of Ants: 10
alpha: 1
beta: 1
evaporation rate: 0.1
initial_pheromone: -1
iterations 4096
alpha_ 1
Before calling run: 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040a1f0 in main ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040a1f0 in main ()

Comment: @Jose: Can you confirm that `colony` is not `NULL`?

Comment: @Jose: Incidentally, you really shouldn't be using `malloc` in C++ code!  Switch to `new`.

Comment: I have realized that calling directly the GPSimpleAntColony is solved, but i don' t know why is not working with the base class

Comment: @Jose: I would recommend either stepping in a debugger to see exactly what memory access it's complaining about, or trying to reduce your code to a *minimal* test case that's easier for others to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you're allocating memory with `malloc` without checking the return value. Any chance you're getting back a NULL? Especially with `pheromones_` which appears to require n*n space, and your sample code does not give us the value n.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you every one mates, but it was absolutely a silly thing as always. I had a statical variable that was affecting the execution. Now is working perfectly,

Thank you a lot

cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the base class make run pure virtual or provide a default implementation for it.

```
virtual void run() = 0;
```

In the child class, declare run virtual.

```
virtual void run();
```

EDIT:  The real problem is that the base class run() isn't pure virtual.  As mentioned in comments below the child class run() will automatically become virtual, but I think it is still clearer to explicitly declare it as such.

Compare http://codepad.org/6MlrH5Q4 to http://codepad.org/lBWaEefT

Comment: The linker should detect if there's a missing body for the base class `run`, and C++ will automatically make all child `run` methods with the same signature virtual, even if they aren't declared as such.